# How to json dump tweepy stream into text file?

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

Hi I have looked at many guides and tutorials on how to do this, but I am having trouble with being able to use tweepy to store the JSON data in a text file.

```
class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener): 

def on_status(self, status):

    print(status)

def on_error(self, status):

    print status
    if status == 420:

        return False



if __name__ == '__main__':

stream_listener = StreamListener()
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, stream_listener)
```

I have another python file which is supposed to read data into a list:

```
import pandas
import json

json_data = 'twitter_data.txt'

data_list = []
#load file 
tweets_file = open(json_data, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
try:
    tweet = json.loads(line) #this line causes problems
    data_list.append(tweet)
except:
    continue


print len(data_list)
```

I thought the data received from twitter comes in JSON format, and the guides I'm following all say it does, but it's actually in another object.

Should I just store everything in a list then json dump that list into the new text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're on the right track. You can modify the stream listener to write tweets to a file directly.

**Edit:** this now writes out in JSON format.

```
#Import the necessary methods from tweepy library
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import API

#Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
CONSUMER_KEY = #YOUR CONSUMER KEY
CONSUMER_SECRET = #YOUR CONSUMER SECRET
ACCESS_TOKEN = #YOUR ACCESS TOKEN
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = #YOUR ACCESS TOKEN SECRET

class FileWriteListener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self):
        super(StreamListener, self).__init__()
        self.save_file = open('tweets.json','w')
        self.tweets = []

    def on_data(self, tweet):
        self.tweets.append(json.loads(tweet))
        self.save_file.write(str(tweet))

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True


auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = API(auth)

twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())
# Here you can filter the stream by:
#    - keywords (as shown)
#    - users
twitter_stream.filter(track=['hello'])
```

This code will run indefinitely, so you either need to exit the process after some time (Ctrl-C) or modify the code.

Then you can load the data:

```
import json

json_data = []
with open('tweets.json','r') as f:
    json_data.append( json.loads(f.readline()) )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate the response and help, but would this let me use json.loads when reading from the new file? I don't believe it is in JSON format to begin with, right?

Comment: Just a heads up, this contains the entire json file as one object and stores it in the list, making the list length only 1. But each entry in the list should be a tweet.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this may be what your looking for.

```
def on_status(self, tweet):
    json_dumps = json.dumps(tweet._json)
    tweet_json = json.loads(json_dumps)
    print(tweet_json['created_at'])
```

These are all the keys you can use in the tweet_json[  ]

dict_keys(['created_at', 'id', 'id_str', 'text', 'source', 'truncated', 'in_reply_to_status_id', 'in_reply_to_status_id_str', 'in_reply_to_user_id', 'in_reply_to_user_id_str', 'in_reply_to_screen_name', 'user', 'geo', 'coordinates', 'place', 'contributors', 'retweeted_status', 'is_quote_status', 'quote_count', 'reply_count', 'retweet_count', 'favorite_count', 'entities', 'favorited', 'retweeted', 'filter_level', 'lang', 'timestamp_ms'])